# MFC how to display a list of objects

Tags: c++, vector, mfc

I have a collection `users` and I want to display them in a `ListBox` or grid (like `DataGrid` in WPF) using MFC Library. I use `List Control` but it seems difficult to manipulate it. Is there another simple control to manipulate structure and collections in MFC?

Comment: The list control widget is pretty simple. Please show what you have tried and tell us where you have difficulties. And tell us a bit more about your application.

Comment: Search "list control mfc" on google, 4th hit should explain everything you need.

Comment: I don't know WPF, I am sure it has ListBox. What is DataGrid in WPF? `List Control` is `ListView` not `ListBox`. `ListBox` is simple, `ListView` is more complicated and more powerful. Pick one.

Comment: `for ( const User& u : users ) { m_ListCtrl.InsertItem( MAX_INT, u.toString() ); }`

Comment: MFC has both CListBox and CListCtrl, if you need only one column, the first is much easier to use, but you need the second if you need multiple columns.

Comment: @DavidChing: A `CListCtrl` supports multiple columns just fine (see [CListCtrl::InserColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz5b6131.aspx). Inserting sub items requires the generic [CListCtrl::InsertItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9s12fc.aspx) overload, taking an `LVITEM*` parameter.

Comment: @IInspectable:  yes, the question is if one column is all that is needed then CListBox could be used more easily instead. The question is not clear.